# When deployed on Vercel, my swagger ui shows a blank page (NodeJs NestJS Swagger)

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, swagger, vercel

Im having the follow issue, on localhost it works fine, and, on AWS EC2 server too, but when i deply the application on Vercel, the path that should show my Swagger UI (like: localhost:8080/swagger), it only shows a blank page. As i said, when i deploy anywherelse it works fine, with the exactly same repositoy, but on vercel, it show a blank page.

Someone have any ideia about what can be happening? I've seached about it but without success.

Ps: I realized that some people have a issue that the swagger ui load but doesnt load the css files, but that is not my case. In my case i have a literally blank screen.

Thank you very much.

Im using Nestjs as main framwork
My nestjs/swagger version: 7.0.3
My node version: 18.17.0

I tried update the swagger version and didnt worked. I tried to host my application in other place (like aws ec2) with the same repo and worked, but on vercel, is not.

Comment: Are there any errors in the Network and Console tabs in the browser dev tools?

Comment: Just checked and no, no errour found on the logs after deploying on Vercel.

Answer (score 0):

Try using "swagger-ui-express": "^4.6.2"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).